# Wordpress Ajax always returns a 404 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, javascript, html

I just got this code from a tutorial. I can't seem to get it to work.

HTML (home.php)

```
    <form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
      <!-- The Name form field -->
      <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
      <br>
      <!-- The Email form field -->
      <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>  
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/> 
      <br>
      <!-- The Submit button -->
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
   </form>
   <!-- We will output the results from process.php here -->
   <div id="results"><div>
```

PHP (function.php)

```
    function myform(){
       echo "Form submitted successfully: <br>Your name is <b>".$_POST['name']."</b> and your email is <b>".$_POST['email']."</b><br>"; 
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_myform', 'myform');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myform', 'myform');
```

Javascript (header.php)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            jQuery.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', jQuery("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                jQuery('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the question? "I can't seem to get it to work" isn't much of a trouble ticket.

Comment: Well, basically I'm asking why I'm getting a 404? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

This was very frustrating to figure out. I spent hours on this issue and discovered your problem is in this input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>
```

Try changing the input field name to anything but "name", for example:

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a list of reserved names, where if you use one in your forms, wp will bork, usually with no good error.

Comment: Unbelievable. WP doesn't like the term used as the name for a POST body property so it throws a 404?!?!?! So stupid.

Comment: Here they are: https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting a 404 on the AJAX request, then your path is wrong. Use `admin_url` to construct the path rather than hard-coding it.

```
jQuery.post(<?php admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>, // ...
```

You are probably better off printing the admin url address to a Javascript variable via [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) than you are printing it directly in the template. For example:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');   
wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'my_ajax_vars', array(
    'ajaxurl'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
);
```

You are usually better off [registering](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [enqueuing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) scripts rather than writing them directly into templates, especially `header.php`. As written, what your javascript loads on every page and I doubt it is needed on every page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sanitize all your data.

Second, I will rather do this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            //if you don't have your script localized and you will add it in header.php (not a good practice)
            $.post(
               '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php); ?>',
               form.serialize(),
               function(data){
                   //just to check the data
                   console.log(data);
                   $('#results').html(data);
               }

            });
            jQuery.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', jQuery("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                jQuery('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And in your php (functions.php) file:

Be sure to add die(); at the end of the functions.

```
function myform(){
       echo "Form submitted successfully: <br>Your name is <b>".$_POST['name']."</b> and your email is <b>".$_POST['email']."</b><br>"; 
       die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_myform', 'myform');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myform', 'myform');
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in this line `'<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php); ?>',` so I changed it to `'<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',` but I still get a 404 error. Any idea why I'm getting a 404?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put your (wp) action in the form or jQuery ajax function.

add `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myform">` to the form and it will hook on your ajax functions.